# Change background color to item range of ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have this particular need:

When I click on a `Button`, some items of my `ListView`should be highlighted - usually one line or a range of lines, not random elements - by changing the background color. 
Does android offer such feature? 
I was thinking to add a method in my custom adapter to set a line range, then adding a check in `getView` method to decide if setting standard or highlighted background and finally notify the adapter that the data has changed, but I'm quite sure there's something that allows this without repopulating the whole `ListView`.

I'm aware of multiple selection, but I think it's quite different, isn't it?

**UPDATE:** using `list.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);` I'm getting a `NullPointerException`because it only contains the visible children, not all the items. Isn't there any alternative solution?

**UPDATE2:** See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

In MyAdapter class:

```
private boolean highlighted = false;
private Integer from, to;
//....
public void setHighlight(int from, int to) {
    if ((this.from != null && this.from == from) && (this.to != null && this.to == to)) {
        highlighted = false;
        this.from = null;
        this.to = null;
    } else {
        highlighted = true;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
}
//...
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup vg) { 
    parsedLine entry = lines.get(pos);
    //...
    if (highlighted && pos>=from && pos<=to){
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Theme.getHighlightColor()));
    } 
    //...
    return v;
}
```

Then wherever I want to highlight some lines:

```
MyAdapter myadapter = (MyAdapter)mylist.getAdapter();
myadapter.setHighlight(from, to);
myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mylist.setSelection(from);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to highlight list item when your button is pressed.
Put this code on button's onClick event.

```
listview.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: I'm getting a NullPointerException at that line, though I can see the listview and it's populated. I'm afraid that this happens because the child that I'm trying to edit isn't visible on screen but needs to be initialized by making it visible, even if adding setSelection(pos) before doesn't work.

Comment: Try to print your edittext value see what you get and change final EditText input = new EditText(getApplicationContext()) to final EditText input = new EditText(YourActivity.this)
then run your program.

Comment: I get a valid input, because setSelection works without getChildAt. The problem, as i suspected, is that it works only for visible lines. Meaning that this won't work on a 1500 items list as in my case.

Answer (score -1):

@Vektor88 - Please try change once

```
 final EditText input = new EditText(CLASSNAME.this);
```

Comment: It's the same, the text is valid, it crashes once i click ok and it tries to change the color, because it only works on visible items. If i have 1500+ rows it's impossible that android shows them all.